# Are there any good Scala-specific frameworks and libraries worth taking a look out there?

Tags: scala, frameworks

Are there any good Scala-specific frameworks (for whatever purpose) and libraries worth taking a look out there other than Lift web framework?

Answer (score 6):

Let's see:

- Akka -- Distributed Computing
- Scalaz -- Functional Programming (above and beyond what Scala provides)
- ScalaCheck -- Testing framework with auto-sampling
- ScalaTest / Specs2 -- Traditional testing frameworks

These are my favorites. Of course, there are many libraries out there, but it would be pointless to list here all interesting Scala libraries that exist.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not as popular as some of the others, but I think these really show off what Scala can do:

[Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/introduction.html) - Basically a typesafe SQL DSL

[Scalatra](http://github.com/scalatra/scalatra#readme) - Ruby Sinatra clone

[Play Framework Scala Module](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1-trunk/scala) - Scala programming for Play

Comment: Thanks! At the first glance, Squeryl seems to be a thing among those I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

[Akka](http://akkasource.org/), to be certain.

Answer (score 4):

- [scala xray](http://github.com/harrah/browse) shows how to use a
  compiler plugin for good effect.
- [sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/) for sure. It's a marvel.

Answer (score 1):

[Circumflex ORM](http://circumflex.ru/orm.html) - raw but very interesting framework for object-relational mapping.

Answer (score 1):

[scalate](http://scalate.fusesource.org/) for templating and [scalala](https://code.google.com/p/scalala/) for linear algebra are well worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter folks have produced some nice libraries. We're leveraging:

[Querulous](http://github.com/nkallen/querulous) (http://github.com/nkallen/querulous): for easy database access via JDBC

and

Configgy (http://www.lag.net/configgy): for accessing file-based configuration data

Comment: Note that Querulous is abandoned

Comment: As is Configgy - see http://robey.lag.net/2012/03/26/why-config.html

Answer (score 0):

[Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) for making HTTP requests (synchronous or async) and handling responses by defining closures.  Its use of symbols can be controversial, but I'm a fan.